# Skip wrong password for 7z extraction Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, 7zip

The task is to extract files from multiple password-protected archives stored in “IN” directory with 7zip package, passwords stored in list “PASS”. I have a problem: when the password is wrong 7zip creates empty folders and files. Are there any ways to skip wrong password and go to next iteration?
Here’s my bash script

```
FILES=./IN/*
PASS=(‘1’ ‘2’ ‘3’)
for f in $FILES
do
 for psd in $(PASS[@])
  do
   if 7z x -y -p”$psd” -o./OUT $f | grep ‘ERROR’; then
    break
   fi
  done
done
```

Comment: I don't know the command line interface for `7z`, but I suspect that if a problem occurs, the message is written to standard error, not, as you assume, to standard output. Also, I could imagine that `7z` is setting an exit code > 0 in the presence of error, and if this is the case, this is also something you could check.

Comment: 7z will end with a non 0 exit code in case of wrong password, so you can just use it like so: `7z x -y -p”$psd” -o./OUT $f || break` But the logic is broken here, coz if the first pass is wrong then whole loop will be skipped, you should use `continue` instead. And `break` should be used in case of success.

Comment: Here it is: `7z x -y -p”$psd” -o./OUT $f && break || continue`

Comment: @Ivan this should be instead of ‘if’ statement?

Comment: And for loop over files it's better to use this: `for f in ./IN/*; ...`, coz if you have files with spaces in name they'll be splinted in $FILES var.

Comment: @Ilya yes, actually `|| continue` is redundant, `&& break` is enough.

Comment: @Ivan unfortunately it doesn’t work:( now I have: for psd in &(PASS[@]) do 7z x -y -p”$psd” -o./OUT “$f” && break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion : use `7zz t` (test archive integrity) to determine if a given password in your list is valid *before* attempting extraction.

Example:

```
#! /bin/sh
                                                                                                                                                                                               
WORKDIR='path/to/your/work/dir'

PW='1 2 3'

for File in "$WORKDIR"/*.zip
do  test -r "$File"   ||   continue
    for Password in $PW
    do  7zz t -p"$Password" "$File" >/dev/null 2>&1 \
        &&   { 7zz x -p"$Password" "$File";   break; }
    done   ||   echo "warning: could not extract file \"$File\" (no valid password found)"
done
```

###### Note:

- if you've installed package "7zip", the archiver command name is `7zz`.
- if you've installed package "p7zip-full" (the Unix CLI port of 7-Zip), the archiver command name is `7z`.

---

Tested on Linux Debian 11.

Hope that helps.